# Is it safe to close the mongod process with docker stop?

Tags: mongodb, docker

When I use docker-compose to create MongoDB containers below, this image is my MongoDB image based on centos. Can using docker stop safely shut down the mongod process?
I learned that the docker stop command will send a SIGTERM signal to processes with PID 1, but I'm not sure whether the process of mongod can receive it in the current situation, because from the following situation, the PID of mongod is 9.

```
mongodb:
  image: mongo:centos
  command:  sh /home/mongo/scripts/compose/noauth.sh 27017
  hostname: mongodb
  ports:
  - 27017:27017
  volumes:
  - /home/mongo/mongo_data:/home/mongo/mongo_data
  - /home/mongo/mongo_log:/home/mongo/mongo_log
```

This is the script of noauth.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d /home/mongo/mongo_data/data_$2/ ];then
mkdir -p /home/mongo/mongo_data/
fi
/home/mongo/mongo_server/bin/mongod --shardsvr --fork --dbpath /home/mongo/mongo_data/ --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 --port $1
```

This is the process in the container.

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
mongo        1     0  0 Jun16 ?        00:00:58 sh /home/mongo/scripts/compose/noauth.sh 27017
mongo        9     1  0 Jun16 ?        01:03:58 /home/mongo/mongo_server/bin/mongod --shardsvr --fork --dbpath /home/mongo/mongo_data/ --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid the shell script wrapper that's pid 1 in your `docker exec ps` output.  The easiest way is to use the shell [`exec`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_20) built-in, which replaces the script with the program you're running.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
#      ^^ prefer plain `sh` when an option

#         v  make sure to quote strings  v
if [ ! -d "/home/mongo/mongo_data/data_$2" ]; then
  mkdir -p /home/mongo/mongo_data
fi

#vvv this `exec` removes the shell wrapper
exec /home/mongo/mongo_server/bin/mongod \
  --shardsvr \
  --fork \
  --dbpath /home/mongo/mongo_data \
  --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 \
  --port "$1"
```

You shouldn't need to explicitly name the `sh` interpreter in your Compose `command:`.  (And these paths don't seem like they're the paths the [Docker Hub `mongo` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) uses; if this is a custom image, make this be your image's `CMD` and not a Compose override.)

Once you do this you should see the database as pid 1 when you `docker-compose exec mongodb ps -ef`, and then it will receive the `docker stop` signal as normal.

Comment: This is a common mirror, the startup parameters of mongod may be different, so I put the startup command in docker-compose.